# Is a Secondary Index in MySQL the Same Thing As a Non-Clustered Index in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql

I am assuming that a secondary index in MySQL is the same thing as a non-clustered index in SQL Server.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer through another forum.  They are indeed the same

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

> In InnoDB, the records in nonclustered indexes (also called secondary
>   indexes) contain the primary key columns for the row that are not in
>   the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for
>   the row in the clustered index. If the primary key is long, the
>   secondary indexes use more space, so it is advantageous to have a
>   short primary key.

Could have just searched for this.

Comment: I did a couple of Google / StackOverflow searches and there were no immediate results so I thought I start a question for future search engine references